# Download a zip file and extract a specific file in Shiny App

Tags: r, amazon-s3, shiny

I have a RShiny app where I fetch a zip file from a s3 bucket using aws.s3 library. I have a specific file within this zip archive that users will download upon clicking `downloadButton`.

Below is a snippet from my server part of the code

```
  rvalues <- reactiveValues(r = file())

  observe({
    rvalues$r <- tempfile(fileext = paste0(".", tools::file_ext("MyArchive.zip")))
    r <- save_object(bucket = MyBucket, 
                     object = "MyArchive.zip", 
                     file = rvalues$r, 
                     key = accesskey, 
                     secret = secretKey, 
                     region = region)
  })
 
  output$download <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() {
      "Sample.json"
    },
    content = function(file) {
      unzip(rvalues$r,"Sample.json")
    }
  )
```

I am creating a temp file and saving the zip from s3 to this temp file. From this temp file, I am unzipping my specific file and passing it to the download handler function. For some reason, this doesn't work. Any help/guidance is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try the following code (I have not tried it since you don't provide a reproducible example):

```
  output$download <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() {
      "Sample.json"
    },
    content = function(file) {
      filepath <- unzip(rvalues$r,"Sample.json")
      file.copy(filepath, file)
    }
  )
```

Comment: Sorry, there are no open s3 buckets that I know to provide a fully reproducible example. I tried yours and it doesn't work. The reactive value r seems to hold the file location, but unzip inside download handler doesn't work.

Comment: @SiddharthArthi Do you get an error message? What does it say? Otherwise, what kind of error do you get?

Comment: I do not get any error, however a failed download starts with file name 'download.htm'

Comment: @SiddharthArthi Hmm... could you try `file.rename` instead of `file.copy`? Are you sure there's a file named `Sample.json` in the zip?

Comment: file.copy did work! Apparently I have been using actionButton instead of downloadButton in the UI :)